# SQL Update Statement Using Join

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I am trying to update a row in a database. I am uploading data into a temp table through my program and then moving that data to the main table after it has been converted. For example I upload a file into my temp table which has 2 rows: First row is Personal ID and the second is shoe brand, with the shoe brand being the primary key. I also have a shoe brand table where say Nike is row 1, Adidas row 2, Reebok row 3 and Shoe_Brand_Name is the name of the column with the name and Shoe_Brand_ID is the ID associated with the name.

When I upload my data to my temp table it will look like this:

```
              TEMP_TBL

Personal ID              Shoe Brand
  123456                    Nike
```

But when I move it to my main table I am using an insert with left outer join and the same data as above in the main table will look like this:

```
              MAIN_TBL

Personal ID              Shoe_Brand
  123456                      1
```

Here is where my problem comes in. Say the user uploads another file with the same Personal ID, and the difference is the shoe brand changes from Nike to Reebok. I would need the main table to update to this:

```
         MAIN_TBL (After Update)

 Personal ID              Shoe_Brand
  123456                      3
```

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
UPDATE [MAIN_TBL]
SET [Shoe_Brand] = b.[Shoe_Brand_ID]

FROM [TEMP_TBL] a
left outer join [MAIN_TBL].tbl_shoebrand b on (a.[Shoe Brand] = b.Shoe_Brand_Name)

WHERE [Personal ID] = '123456'
```

This code runs, but does nothing..... literally nothing.

Can anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using `SQL Server`?  Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
update m
set m.shoebrandid = sb.shoebrandid
from main_tbl m
  join temp_tbl t on m.personalid = t.personalid 
  join shoebrand sb on t.shoebrand = sb.shoebrand
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e954c/1)